# Unhealty backend after scaling up App service plan

Tags: azure

I have an application gateway running with a web application in a App service plan. The application gateway listens and passes requests to the backend, which is the web app. There is a health probe implemented that works fine.

The web app was reachable fine until I scaled up the Service plan. Suddenly the health probe timed out reaching the backend and I got a 502 bad gateway error in the browser trying to reach the web application. After hours the website suddenly was back and the backend was healthy again. I was under the impression that you could scale up and down the App plan without any noticeable effect on the website, but it seems the gateway was not playing along.

Did I configure something wrong or should this work like I assumed?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in environment create app service running with application gateway and got a 502 error.***

The number of TCP connections allowed by the plan standard while is an older it contains the double make sure while scaling up and down in app service try to remain in same tier so that inbound IP will wait for sometimes and then scale back.

Try to update your default setting in **configuration ->General** **setting**-> **ARR Affinity Off**. Either your application isn't stateful, or the session state is kept on a distant service like a cache or database. And try to Run your application with a minimum of 2-3 instances to prevent from failure.

You can make use of app service  [diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics) gives you the right information to more easily

[image]

For ***Reference:***

[Get started with autoscale in Azure - Azure Monitor| Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-get-started#route-traffic-to-healthy-instances-app-service)

[Guide to Running Healthy Apps - Azure App Service](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/05/15/Robust-Apps-for-the-cloud.html)

---

*And I got the same error in application gateway as well to avoid the issue*

***In your virtual network -> service endpoint -> Add endpoint `Microsoft.web` in default subnet***

[image]
.
[image]